# Angular paramMap.getAll - clarification?

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 4 added support for `paramMap` with `get` and `getAll` methods :

I can understand this code which yields the `"id"` value

```
route.paramMap.subscribe(
     params => this.productID = params.get('id')
     );
```

But I don't understand the [usage](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#getAll) for `getAll(?)` :

> `getAll(name: string):  string[]` Return an array of values for the given
>   parameter name.

I've seen [*here*](https://www.opcito.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-angular-4/) an example which states :

```
params:string[] = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.getAll();
```

> this interface offers methods like get() to get specific value  and
>   getAll() to get all values.

I can understand the "get all values" part. but I don't understand the "get all values BY NAME" - which is `getAll(name: string)`

**Question:**

When would I use the `getAll(param)` method ? I mean I will/should only have  unique  parameter/s names. So how come `getAll("id")` can yield more than one value ?

<sub>*An example  would be much appreciated.*</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an array as a param, so if you navigate like this

```
this.router.navigate(['example', { foo: ['bar', 'baz'] } ]);
```

The you can use the `getAll()` function this way:

```
getAll("foo")
```

It will return all the param values: `['bar', 'baz']`

Comment: It supports arrays, your route can be defined this way: example/:foo where foo can be everything, included an array

Comment: From my testing I can even not declare the param and still get it value : https://plnkr.co/edit/BlcdT9VVSwqq84s3XnA0?p=info

Answer (score 3):

Given a navigation like this: 

`this.router.navigate(['example', { foo: ['bar', 'baz'] } ]);`

getAll() will return all the values. use it like this:

`getAll("foo")`

Comment: In the example he provided, foo is probably meant to be 'foo'.